# Multiple thumbnails before image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, thumbnails

I am very unexperienced in Javascript/Jquery therefore I use the [JavaScript Load Image plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) to handle the front end of my image upload process.
**The Problem:**
 I would like to **upload multiple images**, not just one, and therefore also would like to **display all the images, which are to be uploaded as a thumbnail**. At the moment just one image is shown as a thumbnail.
[**The Fiddle:**](https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/1/) https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/1/ (displaying just one thumbnail)
 
**HTML** (the relevant parts)

```
<!-- FILE INPUT -->
<p><input type="file" name="images[]" id="upload-post-images" multiple></p>

<!-- THUMBNAILS -->
<div id="result" class="result">
    <p>This only works in browsers with support for the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL">URL</a> or <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader">FileReader</a> API.</p>
</div><br>
```

**My attempt to loop through the to be uploaded images:**

```
replaceResults = function (img) {
        var content;
        var imageFiles = document.getElementById("upload-post-images"),
        filesLength = imageFiles.files.length;

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            if (!(img.src || img instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)) {
                content = $('<span>Die Bilddatei konnte nicht geladen werden.</span>');
            } else {
                content = $('<a target="_blank">').append(img)
                    .attr('download', currentFile.name)
                    .attr('href', img.src || img.toDataURL());
            }
            result.children().replaceWith(content);
            if (img.getContext) {
                actionsNode.show();
            }
        } // end for loop
    },
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

**=== E D I T ===**
In [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/2/) the thumbnails are placed after the closing form tag:

```
 </form>
 <img src="blob:https%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/001bd1f5-1cce-4618-bc83-9c8bd24f9e90" width="200" height="150">
 <img src="blob:https%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/001bd1f5-1cce-4618-bc83-9c8bd24f9e90" width="200" height="150">
```

In my project (using your code) the thumbnail is placed within the result div:

```
<div id="result" class="result">
    <a target="_blank" download="image.jpg" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBO3sSxiFIz6LUNoB9b27d/p9/HzNSojY7M+FCmPOnGAsrVBWlKSGsSfG4GBNOzbIWtW38xtqwSLsTpzHF7/N4n7PwQgrIo5fh...></a>
    <canvas width="265" height="354"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Is there any chance that you would happen to have an idea why this is or how I could change that?!**
Thank you so much for your tremendous help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your on change function to this:

```
document.getElementById('upload-post-images').onchange = function (e) {
    for(i = 0; i<=e.target.files.length; i++)
    {
       loadImage(
          e.target.files[i],
          function (img) {
              document.body.appendChild(img);
          },
          {maxWidth: 200} // Options
       );
    }
};
```

Here is updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/2/

Earlier your event handler looked like this:

```
document.getElementById('upload-post-images').onchange = function (e) {
    loadImage(
        e.target.files[0],
        function (img) {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        },
        {maxWidth: 200} // Options
    );
};
```

So beacuse of this line:

```
e.target.files[0]
```

You always pass only one image (first) from image array.

Enjoy! :)

**UPDATE**

Regarding your update - so basically it's all about the second parameter in loadImage function.

Comment: Great!  That did not solve my problem, but at least now I know that this part should be working. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my question. Is there any chance that you could point me in the right direction with this? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @kringeltorte Regarding your update in your jsFiddle there are defined some functions like replaceResults, displayImage etc. Also there is variable var result = $('#result') and this is your result div. In jsfiddle those functions are not used, but I guess that in your they are. And for example this line: result.children().replaceWith(content); can cause that your images are append into div result. So basically it's all about the second parameter of loadImage function in js fiddle it is : function (img) {
              document.body.appendChild(img);
          },

Comment: Aha!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: `the second parameter in loadImage function`, meaning the following?`loadImage(thumbnail, function(img) { thumbNode.append(img).show(); }` So the img variable has to be an array and not a single image, is that the right thinking path?

Comment: No, img is single image you need to execute loadImage function in loop like in jsFiddle which I updated

Comment: Check my previous comment. So basically loadImage function works only with one img in time, but if you want to load several images run loadImage function in loop

Comment: Aha!! That helped me a lot! Thank you so much for all your time and effort!!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `upload-post-images` change event like following.

```
document.getElementById('upload-post-images').onchange = function (e) {
    $.each(e.target.files, function () {
        loadImage(
          this,
          function (img) {
              document.body.appendChild(img);
          }, {
              maxWidth: 200
          } // Options
        )
    });
};
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/3/)

Comment: Thank you! Piotr Czarnecki was a little bit faster and more ellaborate. Therefore I went with his answer.

Comment: I edited my question. Is there any chance that you could help me out? Thank you so much for your help!!